# Boost python shared library issue in specific case

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am trying to extend my c++ library which is created using qtcreator to python with boost::python. I create a setup.py like following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension 
module1 = Extension('FOO',
        include_dirs = ['/usr/include/python3.4', '/home/user/cppProjects/FOOLib','/usr/include', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dit-packages'],
        libraries = ['python3.4', 'boost_python-py34', 'boost_thread', 'boost_system', 'FOOLib'],
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/', '/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu/','/home/skywalker/cppProjects/build-FOO-Desktop-Debug/'],       
        sources = ['pythonprovider.cpp'],
        extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'])
setup(name="PackageName",
ext_modules=[module1])
```

and Bar.h

```
class Bar
{
   public:
     Bar(boost::python::list args)
     {
       ...
     }

     static void SetN(int n)
     {
          Bar::N = n;
     }
     static int N;
};
```

and Bar.cpp

```
int Bar::N;
```

pythonprovider.cpp is

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(FOO)
{
   class_<Bar>("Bar", init<list>());
}
```

Compiling the library and using in c++ app is working fine.
I am typing the following code in terminal and installation of python module is working fine.

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Including the package in python like

```
from FOO import *
```

working fine. But when i modify the pythonprovider.cpp with static method

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(FOO)
{
   class_<Bar>("Bar", init<list>())
      .def("SetN", &Bar::SetN)
      .staticmethod("SetN");
}
```

compiling and installation working fine but importing the module assert an error

ImportError: libFOO.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This happen to me before. When i move to body of constructor from cpp file to header file problem is solved but in this case it is not solve my problem.